# I'm trying to route to the page userInfo but its not routing " the argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Route\<Object?\>",

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, riverpod

I'm trying to route to userinfo page and it should automatically route to userinfo page but shows me this error " Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Route<Object?>",

the authRepository class is

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:riverpod/riverpod.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_clone/common/helper/show_alert_dialog.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_clone/common/routes/routes.dart';

final authRepositoryProvider = Provider(
        (ref) {
  return AuthRepository(
    auth: FirebaseAuth.instance,
    firestore: FirebaseFirestore.instance,
  );
}
);

class AuthRepository{
  final FirebaseAuth auth;
  final FirebaseFirestore firestore;

  AuthRepository(
      {
        required  this.auth,
        required this.firestore,
      });

  void verifySmsCode({
    required BuildContext context,
    required smsCodeId,
    required String smsCode,
    required bool mounted,

  }) async
  {
    try{
      final credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: smsCodeId,
        smsCode: smsCode,
      );

     await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
     if(!mounted) return;
     Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          Routes.userinfo,
              (route) => false);
    } on FirebaseAuth catch(e){
      showAlertDialog(
          context: context,
          message: e.toString());
    }

  }

  void sendSmsCode({
    required BuildContext context,
    required phoneNumber,
  }) async {
      try{
        await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
            verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
              await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
            },
            verificationFailed: (e){
              showAlertDialog(
                  context: context,
                  message: e.toString());
            },
            codeSent: (smsCodeId, resendSmsCode){
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                       Routes.verification,
                      (route) => false,
                      arguments: {
                         'phoneNumber' : phoneNumber,
                         'smsCodeId'   : smsCodeId,
                      }
              );
            },
            codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String smsCodeId){}
        );
      } catch(e){
        showAlertDialog(
            context: context,
            message: e.toString());
      }
}
}
```

and the route class is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_clone/feature/auth/pages/login_page.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_clone/feature/auth/pages/user_info_page.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_clone/feature/auth/pages/verification_page.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_clone/feature/welcome/pages/welcome_page.dart';
class Routes{
  static const String welcome = "welcome";
  static const String login = "login";
  static const String verification = "verification";
  static const String userinfo  = "userinfo";

  static Route<dynamic> onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings){
      switch(settings.name!){

        case welcome:
          return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const WelcomePage());
        case login:
          return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const LoginPage());
        case verification:
          final Map args = settings.arguments as Map;
          return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) =>  VerificationPage(
                smsCodeId: args['smsCodeId'],
                phoneNumber: args['phoneNumber'],
              ));
        case userinfo:
          return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const UserInfoPage());

        default:
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Scaffold(
            body: Text('No Page Route Provided'),
          ));
      }
  }
}
```

i was expecting it to move to userinfo page which is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_clone/common/extension/custom_theme_extension.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_clone/common/widgets/custom_elevated_button.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_clone/feature/auth/widgets/custom_text_field.dart';

class UserInfoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserInfoPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UserInfoPage> createState() => _UserInfoPageState();
}

class _UserInfoPageState extends State<UserInfoPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text(
          'Profile info',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: context.theme.authAppBarTextColor,
        ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text("Please provide your name and an optional profile photo",
              style: TextStyle(
              color: context.theme.greyColor,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 40,),
            Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(26),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: context.theme.photoIconBgColor,
              ),
              child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3, right: 3),
                child: Icon(
                    Icons.add_a_photo,
                  size: 43,
                  color: context.theme.photoIconColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 40,),
            Row(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(width: 20,),
                const Expanded(
                    child: CustomTextField(
                      autoFocus: true,
                      hintText: "Type your name here",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 10,),
                Icon(
                  Icons.emoji_emotions_outlined,
                color: context.theme.photoIconColor,
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 20,),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: CustomElevatedButton(
          text: 'NEXT',
          onPressed: (){},
          buttonWidth: 90,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the verification page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_clone/common/extension/custom_theme_extension.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_clone/common/widgets/custom_icon_button.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_clone/feature/auth/widgets/custom_text_field.dart';

import '../controller/auth_controller.dart';

class VerificationPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const VerificationPage(
      {Key? key,
        required this.smsCodeId,
        required this.phoneNumber,})
      : super(key: key);

  void verifySmsCode(
      BuildContext context,
      WidgetRef ref,
      String smsCode
      ){
    ref.read(authControllerProvider).verifySmsCode(
        context: context,
        smsCodeId: smsCodeId,
        smsCode: smsCode,
        mounted: true);
  }

  final String smsCodeId;
  final String phoneNumber;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text(
          'Verify your number',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: context.theme.authAppBarTextColor,
        ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      actions: [
        CustomIconButton(
            onTap: (){},
            icon: Icons.more_vert,
        ),
      ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40,),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                child: RichText(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  text: TextSpan(
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: context.theme.greyColor,
                    height: 1.5,
                  ),
                    children: [
                      const TextSpan(
                        text: "You've tried to register +923167970991. wait before requesting an SMS or call with your code ",
                      ),
                      TextSpan(
                        text: "Wrong number?",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: context.theme.blueColor,
                        )
                      ),
                    ]
                ),
                ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 90),
                  child: CustomTextField(
                    hintText: '- - -  - - -',
                    fontSize: 30,
                    autoFocus: true,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    onChanged: (value){
                      if(value.length == 6){
                        return verifySmsCode(
                            context,
                            ref,
                            value,
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Text(
                  'Enter 6-digit code',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: context.theme.greyColor,
                ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 30,),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.message,
                      color: context.theme.greyColor,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 20,),
                    Text(
                      "Resend SMS",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: context.theme.greyColor
                      ),
                          ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                Divider(color: context.theme.blueColor!.withOpacity(0.2),),
                const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.phone,
                      color: context.theme.greyColor,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 20,),
                    Text(
                      "Call Me",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: context.theme.greyColor
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),


              ],
            ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          Routes.userinfo,
              (route) => false);
    }
```

instead of `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` in `authRepository`

Comment: thank you so much it is correct and i just figured the problem out one sec ago but this is a great help